# How does Travis CI work?

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks, cocoapods, travis-ci

I'm using [Tavis CI](https://travis-ci.org) to build a cocoapod project. I'm not sure if build is the right word, because I'm not exactly sure what it is doing.
This is what I believe, and please correct me where I'm wrong and fill in any blanks.

I write a travis.yml file which is a script that sets up the virtual machine, and tests whether importing a pod (cocoapod files) works properly.

The travis script has a few components I'd need for a cocoapod are

- language (self explanatory)
- cache (named cache for build)
- podfile (path to podfile)
- before_install (commands to run to set up the test), and
- script (the test)

## travis.yml

```
language: objective-c
cache: cocoapods
podfile: Example/Podfile
sudo: required
before_install:
- gem install activesupport
- gem install cocoapods
- pod install --project-directory=Example
script:
- set -o pipefail && xcodebuild test -workspace Example/Workspace.xcworkspace -scheme YourApp-Example -sdk iphonesimulator -arch i386 ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO | xcpretty
- pod lib lint
... ... ... ... ... ...
```

The `gem install`s  are because cocoapods. Then `pod install` loads the pod to the project directory.

The `script` then builds the test modules of the project with the `set` and `xcodebuild` commands.
I'm not sure why the pods need to be linted, but then they are as per the [official cocoapod guide](https://guides.cocoapods.org/making/making-a-cocoapod.html)

I'm getting the following error from travis ci:

```
Unable to find a specification for `MyLib`
```

at the line

```
pod install --project-directory=Example
```

The podspec file is valid and it's even uploaded to the [cocoapod master repo](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/tree/master/Specs). I've created another project, used pod install to install MyLib, and even archived it and it all works fine. But Travis CI keeps getting the same error.